# How to set up jupyter tabsets?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, jupyter-notebook

When writting in R markdown you can state something like:

```
# my tabset {.tabset}

## first one

## second one

# another section
```

to get something like the following: (Is it possible to get such behavior in jupyter?)

[image: Rmarkdown tabset]

Comment: That would really be good to have this, I am hoping jupytext can help

Comment: to clarify, are you wanting this to use R, or are Python or Julia okay?